Why is my Shellsort time complexity look linear and nowhere near n^2
i need to compare insertsort to shellsort(with different gaps)
When i tried measuring time for insertsort everything looked fine (it's close to n^2) but for shellsort using Shell gaps results look nowhere near n^2, i know it should be faster than insertsort but i dont think this much is expected, it sorts array, gaps look fine, but results look too fast and linear which shouldn't be the case
I compile in codeblocks using GNU GCC Compiler with -O0
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

void InsertSort(int tab[], int n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        int temp = tab[i];
        int j;
        for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
        {
            if(tab[j]>temp)
            {
                tab[j+1] = tab[j];
            }
        }
        tab[j+1] = temp;
    }
}

void ShellSort(int tab[], int n, int gaps[], int gapsSize)
{
    for(int g = 0; g < gapsSize; g++)
    {
        int gap = gaps[g];
        for(int k = 0; k < gap; k++)
        {
            for(int i=gap+k; i<n; i=i+gap)
            {
                int temp = tab[i];
                int j;
                for(j=i-gap; j>=0; j=j-gap)
                {
                    if(tab[j]>temp)
                    {
                        tab[j+gap] = tab[j];
                    }
                    else{break;}
                }
                tab[j+gap] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}

int* ShellSortGaps(int n, int& gapSize) // SHELL
{
    int k=n/2;
    int counter = 0;
    do
    {
        k = k/2;
        counter++;
    }while(k>0);
    int* gap = new int[counter];
    k=n/2;
    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
    {
        gap[i] = k;
        k=k/2;
    }
    gapSize = counter;
    return gap;
}

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 generator(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 100000000);
    ofstream myFile;
    myFile.open ("results.csv");
    myFile << "N;TIME(s)" << endl;
    int n = 10000; // starting size of array to sort
    do
    {
        int* tab = new int[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            tab[i] = dist(generator);
        }
        int gapsSize = 0;
        int* gapsResult = ShellSortGaps(n, gapsSize);
        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        //ShellSort(tab,n,gapsResult,gapsSize);
        InsertSort(tab,n);
        auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        myFile << n << ";" << duration.count()/1000.0 << endl;
        cout << "N: " << n << " TIME: " << duration.count()/1000.0 << "s" << endl;
        n+=10000;
        delete[] tab;
    }while(n<=250000);
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}


Your datasizes should be much larger for more reliable timings, and you should be using std::steady_clock instead of std::high_resolution_clock. Side notes : Why are you using int* tab = new int[n]; instead of std::vector?.   myFile.close is NOT necessary (read about RAII).  int tab[], int n, should be std::span<int>. (All in all, looks like you've not been taught how to use a current version of C++)

int* gapsResult = ShellSortGaps(n, gapsSize); -- Your code is full of memory leaks.  The ShellSortGaps function returns a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, and I don't see anywhere in the code where you delete this memory.  Also, in ShellSortGaps you are repeatedly calling new[], and that goes on for 250000 iterations.  If you had a single vector, and just called resize instead of repeatedly calling new[], don't be surprised if your timings improve.

When i tried measuring time -- Why measure time when it isn't clear if your sort actually works? According to std::is_sorted, your code doesn't sort successfully, and that is for just one iteration.  Compare it to std::sort which does sort the sequence correctly.  So does it make sense to attempt to time your sort routine when the routine is broken?

How to implement classic sorting algorithms in modern C++?.

Although a Shell (or Shell-Metzner) sort can be O(N2) in the worst case, that's extremely unusual. The normal expectation is more like O(N1.2). For sufficiently large sizes, this is clearly greater than the O(n log n) we expect from HeapSort, QuickSort, IntroSort, etc. But it's low enough complexity to look nearly linear until/unless sizes get really large.
As an aside, over the years, quite a bit of study has been done about the gaps to be used as well. The gaps you're computing (gapK-1 = 2gapK) are generally not ideal considered ideal. A simple modification of that: gapN-1 = 2gapN+1, generally produces significantly better results. Another series that Knuth recommends is gapn-1 = 3gapn+1.
When I've tested, the 3N series does seem to be noticeably faster than 2N, but the +1/-1 part doesn't seem to make nearly as much difference as the books seem to suggest it should. As far as I can tell, the big difference isn't so much in what you get in the typical case, but the fact that the +1/-1 gives more interaction between passes, so it's much more difficult for somebody to engineer a sequence that gives particularly bad results.
As Paul McKenzie pointed out in a comment, your Insertion sort is broken. This not only works, but is about twice as fast:
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        tmp = v[i];
        int j;
        for (j=i; j>0 && tmp<v[j-1]; j--)
            v[j] = v[j-1];
        v[j] = tmp;
    }

That said, it's still pretty slow when the number of items is large. But it does show that an insertion sort doesn't have to quite as much slower than a Shell sort as your test cod indicates. For what it's worth, here's a slightly rewritten test program, to reduce duplication a bit, check that each sort works, compare them to std::sort, and replace the raw new with std::vector (and use the working implementation of insertion sort):
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

void InsertSort(std::vector<int> &v) {
    int tmp;
    int n = v.size();

    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        tmp = v[i];
        int j;
        for (j=i; j>0 && tmp<v[j-1]; j--)
            v[j] = v[j-1];
        v[j] = tmp;
    }
}

std::vector<int> ShellSortGaps(int n) // SHELL
{
    int k=n/2;
    std::vector<int> ret;
    k=n/2;
    while (k>1) {
        ret.push_back(k);
        k=k/3-1;
    }
    ret.push_back(1);
    return ret;
}

void ShellSort(std::vector<int> &tab) {
    int n = tab.size();
    auto gaps = ShellSortGaps(n);

    for(int g = 0; g < gaps.size(); g++) {
        int gap = gaps[g];
        for(int k = 0; k < gap; k++) {
            for(int i=gap+k; i<n; i=i+gap) {
                int temp = tab[i];
                int j;
                for(j=i-gap; j>=0; j=j-gap) {
                    if(tab[j]>temp)
                    {
                        tab[j+gap] = tab[j];
                    }
                    else{break;}
                }
                tab[j+gap] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}

void LibSort(std::vector<int> &t) {
    std::sort(t.begin(), t.end());
}

void test(void (&sort)(std::vector<int> &), std::vector<int> t, std::string const &label) {
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    sort(t);
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();   
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start);
    std::cout << label << " N: " << t.size() << " time: " << duration.count()/1000.0 << "s";
    if (!std::is_sorted(t.begin(), t.end())) {
        std::cout << "(failed)";        
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
}

int main() {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 generator(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1, 100000000);
    for (int n=10000; n<=250000; n+=10000) {
        std::vector<int> tab;
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(tab), n, [&]{return dist(generator); });
        test(InsertSort, tab, "Insertion sort");
        test(ShellSort, tab,  "    Shell sort");
        test(LibSort, tab,    "     std::sort");
        n+=10000;
    };
    return 0;
}

If we really want to see the differences in complexity between the three, it's probably easiest to start by dividing each time by the number of elements, to get a time per element, then display them on a log scale (so we can see changes in each, despite the widely disparate magnitudes):

When looking at time, however, we get a combination of effects from differences in algorithms and hardware, such as caching.
